# real image or drawing in UIView for movement with touches?

Tags: iphone, uiview, touch, draw, gesture

I would like to draw 4 circles on the left and 4 other circles on the right on the screen. The user with his finger can select a circle on the left and moving his finger across the screen would see a line being drawn at the same time whilst he goes for a circle on the right. Some animation would be present, the first circle selected would "change" by being filled when selected, then the line would be drawn and whilst entering the circle on the right - as well this circle would be filled.

The question is simple: a) should I go ahead and draw these circles by hand/programmatically empty and/or filled - OR - b) should I create nice jpgs files for my empty circles, another one for my filled ones and so replace one image by another when user selects a circle whilst really drawing a line on top?

What would be the best solution between a) and b) please? 
What would be the easiest as well please?

Thanks in advance for your help and experience on this.

Cheers,
geebee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option (b) is good! because you don't need to draw circles programetically. Also you can give tags to those image, so that you can find them in UITouch events, and from that in touchMoved event, you'll need to implement logic for draw a line between those two circles.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that the option a, could be a more complex because you need OPENGL. But you could play more like give the option to the user to get more colors.

And the option b is the easiest one for you, but if you want to modify you need to create another image. And your users can only use that colors